# SQL help needed for birthday query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called 'users'. Inside users there are 3 columns: id, name, birth_date(ex: '2015-10-25').

I want to make a query that returns the id's of the users that have birthdays today.
So for I came up with:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE timestampdiff(day, cast(('2015' + '-' + extract(month from date) + '-' + extract(day from date)) as date), now()) % 365 = 0;
```

This is not working, but this is:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE timestampdiff(day, birth_date, now()) % 365 = 0;
```

**This is working because the year in the record is 2015, which is bigger than 2012, which is the first leap year going away from present time. So, if the year in the record would be between 2012 and 2007, the above query should be different in order to work and show the id of the birthday person:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE timestampdiff(day, birth_date, now()) % 365 = 1;
```

So every 4 years further, the number increments.

The question is: is it possible to concatenate strings inside cast functions and use cast inside timestampdiff?
The first query would try to replace the year in the birth_date record. This is needed to avoid leap year differences in modulus result, to keep it 0. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: why don't you do 'where month(birth_date) = month(now()) And day(birth_date) = day(now())' ?

Comment: because I actually need the users which have bdays in 7 days, so I cant use month and day, because if for example I have a bday on the 2nd of the month, that would not work. i need something to give me 7 days difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q:** is it possible to concatenate strings inside cast functions and use cast inside timestampdiff?

**A:** Yes, it's possible to perform string concatenation in that context. (But I can't fathom why that would be needed to solve your reported problem.)

In MySQL, string concatenation is performed using the **`CONCAT`** function, and the the **`+`** operator is the numeric addition operator. But again, I don't know why you would want to do string concatenation.

If you want to replace the "year" portion of a birth_date value, you could use an expression like this:

```
 CONCAT('2016-',DATE_FORMAT( birth_date ,'%m-%d'))
```

---

Assuming that `birth_date` column is `DATE` datatype, then you could something like this to format the date values into strings in consistent "month day" format, which can be compared.

```
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT( birth_date ,'%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT( NOW() ,'%m-%d')
```

You could also check `birth_date` values that match a particular day:

```
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT( birth_date ,'%m-%d') = '01-17'
```

Or that match the day seven days from today:

```
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT( birth_date ,'%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT( NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY ,'%m-%d')
```

Comment: Great, this is clear and exactly what I need. Especially the last query. Thank you!

Comment: There's still a conundrum of `birth_date` values containing Feb 29 **`yyyy-02-29`**. Some leaplings choose to celebrate their birthday on Feb 28th, others choose March 1st. How this condition is handled probably depends on the purpose of the "birth_date" is being used (celebration date,mailing birthday cards,determining age change for insurance, retirement, etc.) and appropriate handling may be informed by applicable rules and policies.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an interval of year? And, although it may look complex, if you don't run functions on the data indexes can be used in the query execution.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e4b85/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE users
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(3), `birth_date` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO users
    (`id`, `name`, `birth_date`)
VALUES
    (1, 'apm', '1985-01-18 00:00:00'),
    (1, 'bpm', '1955-01-18 00:00:00'),
    (1, 'cpm', '1955-01-19 00:00:00')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
      users.*
   , date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL concat(year(curdate()) - year(birth_date),'') YEAR) as calc_date
from users
where birth_date = date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL concat(year(curdate()) - year(birth_date),'') YEAR);
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e4b85/1/0)**:

```
| id | name |                birth_date |                 calc_date |
|----|------|---------------------------|---------------------------|
|  1 |  apm | January, 18 1985 00:00:00 | January, 18 1985 00:00:00 |
|  1 |  bpm | January, 18 1955 00:00:00 | January, 18 1955 00:00:00 |
```

Comment: MySQL may be able to make use of an appropriate index, yes. But a query of this form can't make use of an index "range" scan operation. Yes, `birth_date` is a bare column (on the left side). But the expression on the right side contains a reference to that same column, as well. So that expression has to be evaluated for every row. It's still going to be a full scan of all rows.

Comment: Good point, thanks, but that does not alter the general case (avoiding functions on data). Plus, I prefer to use date math. (This could solve the 29 Feb issue, untested.)